# How to concatenate two streams in Apache Flink

Tags: scala, streaming, apache-flink

E.g. i want to compose stream of `1, 2, 3` and `4, 5` in single one, so result should be: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. In other words: if first source is exhausted - get elements from second one. My closest attempt, which **unfortunately does not preserve items order**, is:

```
val a = streamEnvironment.fromElements(1, 2, 3)

val b = streamEnvironment.fromElements(4, 5)

val c = a.union(b)

c.map(x => println(s"X=$x")) // X=4, 5, 1, 2, 3 or something like that
```

Also did similar attempt with datetime included, but with same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible right now, at least not with the high level DataStream API.

It might be possible to implement a low-level operator that first reads on input and then the other input. However, this will completely block one input which does not work well with the way that Flink handles watermarks and performs checkpoints.

In the future, this will be possible using so-called [side inputs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-17+Side+Inputs+for+DataStream+API).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Formulated underlying problem more precisely in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709208/accumulate-state-until-end-in-apache-flink

Answer (score 3):

If you have N sources (not streams) that you want to order consecutively, then you could wrap them with an outer source. Something like:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.ResultTypeQueryable;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SequentialSources<T> implements SourceFunction<T>, ResultTypeQueryable<T> {

    private TypeInformation<T> type;
    private SourceFunction<T>[] sources;
    private volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    public SequentialSources(TypeInformation<T> type, SourceFunction<T>...sources) {
        this.type = type;
        this.sources = sources;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<T> context) throws Exception {
        int index = 0;

        while (isRunning) {
            sources[index++].run(context);
            isRunning = index < sources.length;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        isRunning = false;

        for (SourceFunction<T> source : sources) {
            source.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<T> getProducedType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also not preserve items order. Now i trying to do it using `InputFormatSourceFunction.format` which seems to be appropriate choice and it has the `reachedEnd: Boolean` function to check - is source exhausted. But it is also not working, due to `JobManager - No InputSplitAssigner for vertex` Flink error and consequent `format` variable NPE.. Any ideas how to [get it work](https://gist.github.com/kell18/2cc8f8ae7b530299c172a4011e2050e6)?

Comment: Hi @kell18 - I'm not sure why you think this doesn't preserve order. I tried it out, and the order of elements printed is the same as (source1 elements) followed by (source2 elements), which was what I thought was needed.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Nice idea @kkrugler! The order will be preserved if all operators have a paralllelism of 1. If the operator that follows the source has a higher parallelism, the records will be round-robin distributed and hence be shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this approximately through a `flatMap` with a heap buffer in it. But actually, it depends some issues. If, e.g. elements from some input stream are delayed, the output will not be strictly ordered.

```
def process(): StreamExecutionEnvironment = {
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

implicit val typeInfo = TypeInformation.of(classOf[Int])
implicit val typeInfo2 = TypeInformation.of(classOf[Unit])

val BUF_SIZE = 3
val STREAM_NUM = 2

val a = env.fromElements(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, Int.MaxValue)
val b = env.fromElements(4, 5, 9, 10 , 11, 13, Int.MaxValue)

val c = a.union(b).flatMap(new FlatMapFunction[Int, Int] {
  val heap = collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[Int]().reverse
  var endCount = 0

  override def flatMap(value: Int, out: Collector[Int]): Unit = {
    if (value == Int.MaxValue) {
      endCount += 1

      if (endCount == STREAM_NUM) {
        heap.foreach(out.collect)
      }
    }
    else {
      heap += value

      while (heap.size > BUF_SIZE) {
        val v = heap.dequeue()
        out.collect(v)
      }
    }
  }
}).setParallelism(1)

c.map(x => println(s"X=$x")).setParallelism(1)

env
}
```

Comment: This function will sort the data. The question was about concatenating streams. Hence, the function tries to solve a different problem. The function also has a few issues. 1) It will persist both streams completely in memory and therefore might kill the program with an `OutOfMemoryError`. 2) It does not use managed state and will lose data in case of a failure.