# Iteration over multiple streams in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My Question in regarding iteration over multiple streams in Apache Flink.

I am a Flink beginner, and I am currently trying to execute a recursive query (e.g., datalog) on Flink.

For example, a query calculates the transitive closure for every 5mins (tumbling window). If I have one input stream inputStream (consists of initial edge informations), another outputStream (the transitive closure) which is initialised by the inputStream. And I want to iteratively enrich the outputStream by joining the inputStream. For each iteration, the feedback should be the outputStream, and the iteration will last until no more edge can be appended on outputStream. The computation of my transitive closure should trigger periodically for every 5 mins. During the iteration, the inputStream should be "hold" and provide the data for my outputStream.

Is it possible to do this in Flink? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a side-input issue, where you want to treat the "inputStream" as a batch dataset (with refresh) that's joined to the other "outputStream". Unfortunately Flink doesn't provide an easy way to implement that currently (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701829/231762)

If both of these streams are coming from data sources, then one approach is to create a wrapper source that controls the ordering of the records. It would have to emit something like a Tuple2 where one side or the other is null, and then in a downstream (custom) Function you'd essentially split these, and do the joining.

If that's possible, then this source can block the "output" tuples while it emits the "input" tuples, plus other logic it sounds like you need (5 minute refresh, etc). See my response to the other SO issue above for skeleton code that does this.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean, practically I want to process the stream in a bulk synchronous way like Spark Streaming. The iteration of input streams should be treated like a bulk iteration. I did consider merging multiple streams together, split them into several streams for each iteration, and re-merge the intermediate results of each iteration again into a new merged stream for the next iteration. However, it adds a lot of redundant computations. And once I add a windowing logic, it becomes a big mess. Thank you for your answer and the related informations.

Comment: After re-reading your response, I think your use case is a bit different. It sounds like you'd want to implement (conceptually) a ProcessFunction that takes as input the edges, accumulates these for 5 minutes, and then triggers the generation of all [i, j] vertex pairs in the transitive closure. For this to scale, you'd have to implement a distributed version of transitive closure. I _think_ you could do this via an iteration, but it's an interesting problem.