# Change source function in Flink without interrupting the execution

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am looking for a solution how I can change a source function in Flink while execution is in progress:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

SourceFunction<String> mySource = ...; // this a function that I want to change during runtime;
DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(mySource); 

stream.map(...).print(); // creating my stream

env.execute("sample");
```

I am thinking about creating a wrapper around a real implementation of `SourceFunction` that will replace the implementation behind the scenes when needed but come across a notion of `SourceContext`.

Answer (score 1):

There was a talk at Flink Forward that looked at some related issues. I think you'd find it helpful. See [Bootstrapping State In Apache Flink](https://data-artisans.com/flink-forward/resources/bootstrapping-state-in-apache-flink).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's useful but doesn't answer the problem I have.

Comment: hi, @StephenL. could you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could connect the stream from the two source functions, and run them into a `CoMapFunction`. Inside of that you can decide which to discard, but that assumes the later source isn't outputting data until you're ready to switch to it.

Comment: It's not something that I am looking for. I would like to have a way to create a new source function on the fly and replaced the existing one with that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, as an alternative you can look at an answer I'd provided previously on SO, with some sample code to [wrap multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692658/how-to-concatenate-two-streams-in-apache-flink). But note Fabian's comment that this will only preserve order if the downstream operator's parallelism is also 1.